# Creating thick, bright pink smoke [UPDATED]

Tags: shaders, smoke-simulation

Ok, I'm slowly going mental here. Yesterday evening I was playing around with smoke and managed to create this lovely thick, bright pink smoke cloud:

[image]

This one is perfect and exactly what I am looking for. It's basically a smoke emitting object inside a glass tube and a smoke collision object right above the tube to disperse the smoke column. Unfortunately I didn't bake the smoke and I've accidentally overwritten the file with the right settings.

Generally, smoke is quite dark. So I used a white absorption color and a negative smoke color to get the bright pink, something along those lines:

[image]

But whatever I do, I'm unable the match the same intensity in the initial image. Emission create white cubes around the smoke bubble, it does not actually intensify the color, so that's not it, either. It might even be a combination of the smoke settings and shader settings. Currently I tried various things, all very disappointing:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I even tried inserting light inside the smoke, but that's even farther from the desired effect.

[image]

Can anyone with more smoke expertise point me into the right direction?

**UPDATE**

In the meantime the issue resolved itself automatically. This seems to be a bug in Blender.

The image below was rendered this afternoon, which shows a lot of issues in the thick areas:

[image]

While far from perfect, the following image got rendered five minutes ago:

[image]

Same file, same settings, quite a different result. I'm not sure what caused these horrible results, which is kind of frustrating. I spent a day trying to get it right, while the settings are not dramatically different between the target image and the ones that have dark artifacts. Maybe a cache issue? I cleared cache between bakes, though.

Comment: Reminds me of my post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233575/unpinning-cloth-not-working where you'll see in the Answer how indeed sometimes blender is not clearing a bad cache.  Consider reporting a bug, as these problems do tend to burn significant amounts of our time (and hair being pulled?).

Comment: This reminded me to enter a bug report.  See https://developer.blender.org/T91034