# Unpinning Cloth not working

Tags: cloth-simulation, vertex-weights

It would seem that I'm following the solution to [Unpinning Cloth Deforms Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165169/unpinning-cloth-deforms-object), but when I animate the Group Remove Threshold from 0.0 to 1.0 in frame 10, my cloth remains pinned instead of releasing.

[image]

What is this [image] example missing?

BTW, I know this works, because from the other link I got the [image] file to work!

Also, to complicate things, I'm looking to make an X-Y array of cloths: would there be some way to "un-pin" the array, at the same or at different times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: solution for 2.93

i just downloaded the newest version of 2.93

just follow the steps:

1. hit delete all bakes
2. hit remove in vertex group to remove the existing pin
3. let the simulation run (just falls down)
4. select that vertex again, give weight 0.999 -> assign

4b) throw salt over your shoulder

5. works

video to show how i did it:  https://youtu.be/a3kXCA_QrwI

---

i think, Blender isn't working 100% here.

I did this on Blender 3.0 alpha - i don't know whether it works on other versions. It sounds weird, but i could reproduce it. So give it a try please:

1. delete all bakes
2. select any other vertex, change weight to .98 -> assign
3. run simulation
4. delete your added vertex from 2 with remove from vertex group
5. run again -> works

Comment: Thanks for you time, Chris.  Unfortunately this did not work for me in 2.93.   I edited my question above where I got the blend file from the other linked question to work!   So there is something subtle that I'm missing -- you know like that missing comma in a java program LOL.

Comment: i am pretty sure you made it right....just Blender seems to "hang" or didn't clean the cache right...

Comment: @james_t: it works also in 2.93, i updated my answer

Comment: You forgot to add the step where I throw salt over my shoulder.  Bad blender, bad blender !    Thanks again, oh great one!

Comment: I am very sorry. I improved my answer.